# Why do I get ORA-12514 with easy connect but not with TNS?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I can connect successfully to my database with a TNS-style connect descriptor:

```
connect <user>/<pass>@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=<host>)(Port=<port>))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=<sid>)));
```

But when I try to connect like this:

```
connect <user>/<pass>@<host>:<port>/<sid>;
```

I get `ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor`.

Why does the fist command work but the second does not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SID and service name are not the same thing. In your working version you're explicitly saying you're using the SID, in the `CONNECT_DATA` part.

When you use the [easy connect syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10836/naming.htm#NETAG255):

> ```
> CONNECT username@[//]host[:port][/[service_name][:server]][/instance_name]]
> Enter password: password
> ```

... you are not supplying the SID; you're actually doing:

```
connect <user>/<pass>@<host>:<port>/<service_name>
```

The service name and SID *might* be the same, but since you're getting that error, in your case they don't seem to be. If you have access to the server you might be able to run `lsnrctl services` to see which service names are recognised. Or if you can connect as a user with sufficient privileges you can query:

```
select value from v$parameter where name = 'service_names';
```

There could be more than one service name reported by either method, and you can probably use any. You may have one like `<SID>.<domain>` which could be an obvious choice. If in doubt though ask you DBA which you should be using.