# istener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, soapui

I tried to connect soapUi the open source version to oracle 11g but this error is raised :

Can't get the Connection for specified properties; java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

this is the connection string :

```
       jdbc:oracle:thin:SYS/imane@127.0.0.1:1521/132
```

ps: I put the driver jar in ext and lib

thank you

Comment: Your DB has a service name of 132? What does `lsnrctl services` report, when run on the DB server machine?

Comment: @AlexPoole 132 is the SID

Comment: You aren't supplying a SID, you are supplying a service name. [This is basically the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26058358/266304), and shows two ways to find the service names you can use. [Also related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37843923/266304); as you're on 11g you can change the URL to use the SID (as `...1521:132`), but it's better to use service names if you can.

Comment: @AlexPoole can you give me the correct syntaxe ?

Comment: I kind of did already, but in full: `jdbc:oracle:thin:SYS/imane@127.0.0.1:1521:132`. But like I said, it would be better to find the correct service name and use that instead of the SID.

Comment: @AlexPoole isn't work I run this command to find the service name:select name from V$ACTIVE_SERVICES; it's display SYS$USERS. so the connection string is jdbc:oracle:thin:SYS/imane@127.0.0.1:1521/orclXDB. but is raise the same error